# How to use leaflet map without internet connection(Offline Mode), preferably in Angular

Tags: angular, leaflet, frontend

I have made an application on Disaster Management using Angular 8 for which I have used Leaflet maps. Now, my professor wants me to run the application without having access to the internet. Is there any way I can use Leaflet maps in offline mode in Angular? I am taking the current position(Lat-Long) of the user and showing it on leaflet maps?

Comment: So many answers: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bleaflet%5D+offline

Comment: [Service workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API/Using_Service_Workers), all the way in.